# Phpstorm, php interpreter is not configured - pasta errada!

Tags: php, html, phpstorm, mamp, interpretador

Galera eu estava fazendo uns códigos marotos em *php* e tava saindo tudo bem, até que eu fui começar a fazer integração *html* com *php*, eu coloco o arquivo *html* na mesma pasta do *php*, na pasta certa do meu *MAMP*(que eu acho q é a htdocs, bom pelo menos estava funcionando certinho até eu tentar integrar(uso mac)), mas quando eu coloco o código pra rodar eu recebo esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olhando a `url` mais profundamente identifiquei que o diretório do *MAMP*, que deveria ser `http://localhost:8888/html5+php/fusao.php?valor=2` estava com os números errados: `http://localhost:63342/html5+php/fusao.php?valor=2`.

No meu *Phpstorm* ele está me dando esta mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei configurar, mas não consegui, olhando o tutorial da *GetBrains*, vi que pra isso eu precisava estar com o *PHP version* instalada, mas por algum motivo não está, eu não consegui entender muito bem como instala, tentei instalar um negocio pelo terminal, mas de nada adiantou. O que acho mais interessante é que, se eu arrumo os numero do site lá em cima ele funciona tal como deveria! Só que quando eu puxo direto do botão eu tenho que ir na url mudar os números de *63342* para *8888*. Como eu posso arrumar isso? O meu *MAMP* se chama apenas MAMP.
Na minha leiguice eu acho que na verdade esta tudo bem configurado, só um diretório que está com problema, mas eu não sei arrumar isso, alguém sabe como dar um jeito?

**Obs:** Meu *Phpstorm* é trial.

Comment: Não entendi o que você está fazendo. Ou pretendendo fazer. Mas erro 502 é erro de servidor. Significa que seu servidor não está ativo. Ligue o apache e veja se o erro continua.

Comment: Um simples programa q calcula a raiz quadrada, mas quando eu coloco o numero e clico no botão para calcular a raiz o diretório q o arquivo php tenta ser achado esta errado.

Comment: Bom, eu não uso MAMP, no Windows eu costumava usar o XAMPP ou o WAMP. Mas eu estou trabalhando em linux. Pois acho melhor para trabalhar com desenvolvimento. Eu desconheço ou nunca precisei fazer essa integração servidor com PHP Storm. Eu uso o PHP Storm apenas como IDE.

Comment: instruções neste link nhttps://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html em Cli interpreter colocar -d-dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 em configuratios option